# Extermly high MySQL CPU%

Tags: mysql, server, cpanel, centos7

Any advice how to solve this problem? this is a new dedicated machine, the MySQL CPU usage strikes to 300% CPU usage[image: 300% CPU usage]

the command:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=127.0.0.1
performance-schema=0
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
innodb_file_per_table=1
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="/var/log/mysql-slow.log"
long_query_time = 2
```

machine is: Intel Xeon E3-1246V3, HDD SATA 2TB, 32GB DDR3
Centos 7.7, CPANEL installed

Comment: to check mysql process, run `show processlist` in mysql client and confirm the result.

Comment: 1 or 2 results like this

83630 user_databaseuser localhost user_databasename Query 1 Creating sort index SELECT id, .........

no slow queries

Comment: maybe creating sort index takes a lot of cpu.

Comment: This model Intel has 4 cores, so 300/4 = 75% effective busy, not a problem for this Linux based server class machine.  Unless it stays at 300% 24 hours a day.  If it stays at 300%, you have a loop somewhere you are not aware of.  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and post the text results for analysis.